# How to say if discriminant belongs to complex plain (quad form)

Tags: python

So i'm trying to write a quadratic solver which will find results whether the coefficients are real/complex or whether the roots are real/complex. So far i've covered everything except for when the coefficients are complex. by saying the `discriminant = b**2 - 4 * a * c` i can account for if discriminant is >, < or == to 0. The only thing i don't know how to do is account for when the discriminant has some complex component of it (for example if a=1, b=-i and c=4). Any idea how I can add that part in? Here's what I have so far for reference:

```
import math
import cmath

def quadSolver(a,b,c, tol = 1e-18):
    print('Equation: {0}x**2 + {1}x + {2}'.format(a,b,c))
    if a==b==0:
        if c!=0:
            print('Has no roots')
        else:
            print('Has an infinite number of roots')
        return

    if a==0:
        print('Has one root')
        print(-c/b)
        return

    discriminant = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    if isinstance(discriminant, complex):
        root1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
        root2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
        print('Has two roots:')
        print(root1)
        print(root2)
    if discriminant > 0:
        root1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2 * a)
        root2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2 * a)
        print('Has two roots:')
        print(root1)
        print(root2)
    elif discriminant == 0:
        root1 = float(-b + math.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2 * a)
        print('Has a double root:')
        print(root1)
    elif discriminant < 0:
        root1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2 * a)
        root2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2 * a)
        print('Has two complex roots:')
        print(root1)
        print(root2)
```

Comment: Just curious, for the case of descrimant==0, why do you compute the math.sqrt(discriminant)?  Wouldn't it be easier to leave it out?

Comment: That's a good question and i guess it's just one of those things i did without realizing it. But i don't see a reason why I'd actually need it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the following if statement can handle a complex discriminant:

```
if isinstance(discriminant, complex):
   root1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
   .
   .
   .
```

I am assuming the problem was checking for a complex discriminant, is this correct?

Edit:

Based on the comment, it sounds like you have to put this as the first "if" statement, and make the if discriminant > 0 and elif.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i was looking for. I just tried it out and although it works fine on it's own, it seems to have a problem when I put it into the whole thing. For discriminant > 0. It says : TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers. However it still gives me the solution when i test it. See my edit